# Background scan BLE in swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am trying to connect with BLE in background but it did not connect in background.
It is working when my app is in foreground.
I am trying to scan with UUID of the peripheral.
Here is the attached code.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

    }


    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

        var msg = ""

        switch central.state {

            case .poweredOff:
                msg = "Bluetooth is Off"
            case .poweredOn:
                msg = "Bluetooth is On"
                let arrayOfServices: [CBUUID] = [CBUUID(string: "CCAExxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")]

                manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices:arrayOfServices, options: nil)
            case .unsupported:
                msg = "Not Supported"
            default:
                msg = "Not Connected"

        }

        print("STATE: " + msg)

    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        print("Name: \(peripheral.name)") //print the names of all peripherals connected.

        //you are going to use the name here down here ⇩

        if peripheral.name == "Name of device" { //if is it my peripheral, then connect

            self.myBluetoothPeripheral = peripheral     //save peripheral
            self.myBluetoothPeripheral.delegate = self

            manager.stopScan()                          //stop scanning for peripherals
            manager.connect(myBluetoothPeripheral, options: nil) //connect to my peripheral

        }
    }
```

How can resolve it?

Comment: Why do you want to connect to the device in the background. Can you tell me exactly what is it you want to do if you were able to connect in the background.

Comment: it is for sending some data i.e. heart bit or it could be any data.i have given nil to options parameter in scanForPeripherals method.is it correct?

Comment: Remove the if that is checking for device name and see what happens. To recognise a known peripheral you should use the identifier, not the name.  The name won't be available when scanning in the background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on 'Background Modes' Capabilities.

And turn on below two option:
     1. User Bluetooth LE accessories.
     2. Act as Bluetooth LE accessory.

Do same as Screenshot:

[image]

Now BLE is working in background mode in iOS application.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is when you instantiate CentralManager you need to instantiate it with a restoration identifier.

Ex:

```
CBCentralManager(delegate: self,options:
[CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: "bleCentralManager"])
```

This is necessary as in the apple documentation it says "Core Bluetooth preserves the state of only those objects that have a restoration identifier".

Then when your app is relaunched into the background you have to reinstantiate your appropriate central manager with the same restoration identifier inside you appDelegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.You can get the restoration identifiers like this:

```
let centralManagerIdentifiers = launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.bluetoothCentrals]
```

Finally in your central managers centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) delegate method you can get a list of all the peripherals the central manager was connected to or was trying to connect to and do whatever want to do in this method.

```
 func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {

    let peripherals = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey]

}
```

Comment: can you tell me what is "bleCentralManager" from where we get this string

Comment: It's unique and chosen by you. Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html